# Java character array to binary string

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary, bit-manipulation

Consider the following character array

```
char[] u = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'a' };
```

I am looking for the most time efficient way in to convert it to a binary string (of the kind 0110) since I need to do some bit shifting and counts on the array in an efficient manner. The array above would be translated to an integer value 6, binary 0110.

I've used a converting to a new string, and then do two replace calls on it, before converting it to an integer with radix 2 but it doesn't look like an efficient way to me.

Any help?

Comment: How do you know 00000001 is just {'b'} and not {'a'a'a'a'a'b}

Comment: Same way you know `1` is `000000001`.

Comment: Cause I know the length of the original char array,as U Mad said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int num = 0;
for(char c : u) {
    num = (num << 1) + (c - 'a');
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
int output=0;
for(int i=0;i<u.length();i++)
    output=output<<1|u[i]-'a';
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile as u is a char array, not a string. If it was a string it still wouldn't compile since the correct method is `charAt` not `getCharAt`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot that. Just replace u.getCharAt(i) for u[i].

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
char[] u = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'a' };
 for(int i=0;i<u.length;i++){
  int y = (int)u[i];
  System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(y));}
```

hope it helps